# Sharepoint 2013 Calendar Views outside ribbon

Tags: 2013, list-view, calendar, ribbon

Is there a way to display all calendar views outside of the ribbon similar to how views are displayed at the top of a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way out of the box is to change the webpart properties and switch the toolbar type to show the toolbar. So you've got at least a menue to switch the view directly above the calendar.